# concatenating string to solr field value while searching?

Tags: search, solr, solrj

is it possible to concatenate string to solr field while we are searching 
Example:
localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=item_type%3Apostings&wt=json&indent=true

now i have one field id i need to append text "locality_" before every id value.so that i need not to to for loop on large data set.

Answer (score 1):

With Solr 4.0 [SOLR-2444](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2444) enables to define alias to a field, apply transformer to the value.
I have not used the above, but you can surely explore on the above either by modifying the value with function query add with constant value or defining a Custom Transformer to apply on a alias field.

Comment: Could you help me with question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554850/solrj-query-get-the-most-relevant-record-first