# Solrj Query - Get the most relevant record first

Tags: solr, schema, solrj

I have some documents in `Solr 4.0`. I want the most relevant records to be displayed first and then the less relevant ones.

For eg, I have 3 documents with titles as follows -

1. Towards Income Distribution Policy
2. Income distribution and economic policies
3. Income Distribution Policy in Developing Countries

Now when I query something like `q=title:Income Distribution Policy`,

I would like document number 3 to show up first (as the first 3 words are an exact match) then I want the document number 1 to show up second (as except for "Towards" the remaining match) then I want the document number 2 to show up (as there are some words in between).

My `schema.xml` looks like this -

```
<types>
  <fieldType name="search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" />
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" />
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
</types>

<fields>
   <field name="title" type="search" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>
```

**EDIT 1 Debug output**

```
"rawquerystring": "title:Income Distribution Policy",
"querystring": "title:Income Distribution Policy",
"parsedquery": "title:incom title:distribut title:polici",
"parsedquery_toString": "title:incom title:distribut title:polici"
```

**EDIT 2 Modified the fieldType**

I used the following combination, still the output is the same.

1. StandardTokenizerFactory - autoGeneratePhraseQueries(not present) -  PorterStemFilterFactory.
2. StandardTokenizerFactory - autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" - PorterStemFilterFactory.
3. StandardTokenizerFactory - autoGeneratePhraseQueries(not present).
4. StandardTokenizerFactory - autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true".
5. WhitespaceTokenizerFactory - autoGeneratePhraseQueries(not present) - PorterStemFilterFactory.
6. WhitespaceTokenizerFactory - autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" - PorterStemFilterFactory.
7. WhitespaceTokenizerFactory - autoGeneratePhraseQueries(not present).
8. WhitespaceTokenizerFactory - autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with `""` around the query string and it worked.

Like - `q=title:"Income Distribution Policy" OR title:Income Distribution Policy`.

This gave me the output as document 1 then document 3 and then document 2. Not perfect but close enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't sort by anything else, you are sorting by Similarity/Relevance. So, if you are not getting the results in the right order, you may need to play with how you are assigning weights and which query parsers you are using.

I assume you are using eDismax with the boost on the title field. In addition have a look at **mm** (minimum match) and **pf** (phrase fields) for boosting.

You may also want to test with autoGeneratePhraseQueries field set on your fieldType.

And, of course, **debugQuery=true** on the queries will help you to see what is going on. You may find that also adding **debug.explain.structured=true** could useful the first couple of times you are trying to read the debug output.

Comment: I executed the query with debugQuery=true and debug.explain.structured=true. What I figured out is in the beginning itself the the rawquery is tokenized i.e. the query is tokenized like this - title:Income title:Distribution title:Policy and therefore the exact matches do not show up. Can you suggest me some solution? I can share the debug output if that helps.

Comment: Try putting autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" on the type definition and see if it improves the results.

Comment: Will try that too. This would need a re-generation of index which might take a little time. Will get back to you. Thank you for the help, I hope it would come in future too.

Comment: The results are the same. 
I tried StandardTokenizerFactory with autoGeneratePhraseQueries true and false(not mentioned). 
I also tried WhitespaceTokenizerFactory with autoGeneratePhraseQueries true and false(not mentioned).
I also tried the above with and without stemming. The results are the same.